# lubuntu 12.04 laptop fails installation if done with livecd

Tags: live-cd

we created livecd on lubuntu 12.04. the following errors are observed: when iso is run on laptop with install option it gives an error as "installation encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installation again." when machine goes into try ubuntu mode the install option link does not work at all.

It is also observed that same iso when tried on Desktops the mouse does not work at all.

Can someone help to sort out these two issues on livecd which is compiled using uck.

Pl. suggest the solution so that changes can be incorporated on livecd.

Comment: can someone help us to resolve the above issue urgently. We are conducting a workshop and during the workshop if this livecd is tried on laptops installation throws above error and if livecd session is opened the keyboard and mouse dont work. Pl. suggest solution urgently.\

Answer (score 0):

Here are somethings to try:

It sounds like the CD disc might be bad, or there might be something wrong with the ISO file.  Try using a different CD disc, and verify the ISO, by running an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

You can also try the 12.04 alternate CD.  Choose the [32Bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-alternate-i386.iso) or the [64Bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-alternate-amd64.iso)  It accomplishes the same as the LiveCD, but the installation is done in text mode.

Try the installation using a USB flash drive instead.  You can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable flash drive,

Comment: the file size is correct also tried cutting iso with usb and then trying installation but surprisingly installation crashes on laptop and on some desktops it does not identify mouse at all. what could be the reason for it.